# How to keep a variable in the copy/paste of windows (CTRL+C a variable in the code)

Tags: vb.net, copy, copy-paste

I want to copy the value of a variable in CTRL+C in a program of vb.net. After the execution of my program, if I press CTRL+V in a notepad, I want to see the value of the variable I copied in the program.

Per example the program would be :

```
Private Sub Program()
    Dim var1 = "I'm a variable"
    CP(var1) 'Here CP is a function which represents the function which copy the value of a variable in CTRL+C

End Sub
```

**So, I search what is the function "CP" if it exists**

If someone can help me... 
Thanks

Comment: `Clipboard.SetText(var1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place where data is stored temporarily when it gets copied is called [the clipboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_%28computing%29).

You're looking for `My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText()`

Microsoft has a [good article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/storing-data-to-and-reading-from-the-clipboard) on how to manage the clipboard on their website.